# how to open files names from directory dialog in pyqt

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

```
path = str(QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select Directory  "))
```

How to read the file form `directorydialog`

Comment: You can select only directories by using `getExistingDirectory`. To select files you need `getOpenFileName`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
file = str(QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Select File", "", "*.png *.jpg"))
print file
```

This will list only `png` and `jpg` files, type the file extension you want to list.